# CSS display inline-block and z-index

Tags: css, z-index

I have this test

CSS:

```
ul li {
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid 1px black;
    z-index:1;
    vertical-align:top;
}
li.hover {
    border:solid 1px red;
    height: 70px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="hover"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b6oumwf5/

I want to make the red item to be over the black ones, to keep the margin between two rows. But now red just make second row move down. Is it possible to realise my idea?

Comment: Create a mock-up of the desired output.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an element inside your li element and then position that element absolutely like the following spinets.

```css
ul li {
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid 1px black;
    z-index:1;
    vertical-align:top;
}
li.hover{
    border: none;
}
span.abs {
    border:solid 1px red;
    height: 70px;
    z-index:2;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="hover"><span class="abs"></span></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
     <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add position absolute in `li.hover` class

```css
ul li {
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid 1px black;
    z-index:1;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    
}
li.hover {
    border:solid 1px red;
    height: 70px;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="hover"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
     <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But when I do this, the red block moves out of the row, and the next black blokc moves to it place, and I want to keep the order. http://jsfiddle.net/b6oumwf5/1/

Comment: @user3571899 That's why you need to use inner element for this. Did you see my answer?

Comment: Bhojendra Nepal thanks! It works! I ll accept your answer!